# Плавное изменение позиции фона

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте! Я не могу понять, как можно сделать плавный эффект изменения позиции фона

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может ли кто-то помочь с получением желаемого эффекта?

Comment: т.е надо чтобы ещё плавнее исчезал фон?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У них фон сделан псевдоклассом `:after` и с помощью анимации `CSS` он плавно уходит за границы элемента:

```css
.block {
  position: relative; 
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.block span {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  z-index: 2;
}
.block:hover span {color: #363636}

.block:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #363636;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  z-index: 1;
}
.block:hover:after {top: 100%;}
```

```html
<div class="block"><span>Портфолио</span></div>
```

Но если вам нужно с помощью скрипта, то вот так:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.block').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({'background-position-y': '-100%'}, 200);
  });
  $('.block').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({'background-position-y': '0%'}, 200);
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  position: relative; 
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(https://srcc.oboi.ws/wallpapers/big_11420_oboi_seryj_fon.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  line-height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.block span {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  z-index: 2;
}
.block:hover span {color: #363636}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block"><span>Портфолио</span></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! то что нужно!)

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav li a {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 22px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #666;
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 100ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 100ms linear;
    transition: all 100ms linear;
}

nav li a.act-link:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
    z-index: -1;
}

nav li a.act-link:hover:before {
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav><ul><li><a class="act-link">Portfolio</a></li></ul></nav>
```